# Detail rows as tabs

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Is there a way to present each detail row (at Master-Detail page) as separate tab or carousel slide? APEX 5.0

I've searched, read and tried for a whole evening, but nothing was found. Tradinional way is present region, not row as tab/carosel slide.

Answer (score 2):

Apex 5.0 doesn't offer such a functionality. There might be some plug-in (search for it, if you want) but that's kind of a *questionable* solution because plug-in doesn't have to work in new Apex releases unless its designer upgrades it as well (or, alternatively, if you are capable of doing that).

If possible, upgrade to the most recent Apex version (currently, it is 19.x). There are numerous *fancy* stuff it offers, one of them being the **Carousel Region**. See how it looks like on the [Universal Theme (Carousel Region)](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:1205:::NO:::) page. Or, create your own workspace on [apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/en/) to see how it works.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this type of region allows you swipe subregions, not rows.